# Installation Failed: Invalid Argument -iOS Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, watchkit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm3Jg.jpg

I am about to build watch app target from existing project. I encountered a strange error upon finishing build that unables me to run the watch app properly. Here is the attached screenshot.

Environment

- OSX 10.10
- XCode 6.2 Beta
- Simulator iPhone 6 iOS 8.2

When I try creating new watch app project and try the Lister demo app they work just fine. So I am suspecting there is something wrong with my existing project but not sure what since the error message is not really explanatory. I appreciate any leads or helps given, thank you for your time.

**EDIT**: After few investigation turns out **extensions** do not work as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After 2 days of research I have found the answer which I believe is an xcode bug.

Basically this is caused by having different build name on your XCode build settings. Making them uniform should solve the problem. As shown here https://devforums.apple.com/message/1047770#1047770

I hope this helps anyone stumbled upon this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "build name"? Are you talking about the "product name"?

Comment: This worked for me!  I renamed my Project Name to match the Product Name (actual App name).

Comment: Great! And so odd. What I had to do is change the entry of "Bundle Name" in Info.plist from `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` to `$(TARGET_NAME)` to ensure the names are identical, even though "Product Name" in Build Settings was already set to `$(TARGET_NAME)`. Perhaps it didn't properly expand the variables.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue. This sequence helped for me:

> Xcode doesn't like it when you have a referenced directory called
>   'Resources' within your resource bundle (see [timrex](http://forums.developer.apple.com/message/39352#17694))

1) **Remove 'Resources' directory from your project's tree;**

2) **Reset content and settings** in iPhone simulator;

3) Press **Shift+Cmd+Alt+K** and click **'Clean'** or **Shift+Cmd+K** in xCode window;

Comment: This fixed my issue. I added a complete folder called Resources to the project and that was the issue. I then created a folder manually and added the files to it, also named Resources, and that worked.

Answer (score 15):

Check if the Bundle Identifier isn't empty in the Info.plist

Answer (score 6):

I got my error fixed by setting the project's "Product Bundle Identifier".
It was empty since my project was being generated by Gyp and I hadn't set that particular setting on the project.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037589/xcode-6-1-installation-failed-invalid-argument-when-trying-to-run-today-appli) and got it resolved by cleaning the phone's memory since it was too low to install the app.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be resolved simply by emptying the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by first building for an actual device - once I'd done that at least once, the simulator ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after I tried everything mentioned here, then deleting the app from the device and restarting XCode. Those two steps were mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232381/1586277

I have no idea what combination of steps fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while running on simulator. I rebooted the system and the issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. My fix was to delete the temporary project files in the derived data folder:

```
rm -R /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname
```

Comment: I have tried this by deleting content of this folder, but it has not helped. After I have deleted whole folder, restarted Mac and emptied trash (as advised by Abdul Shamim), problem is gone. I have not used any extension, so using extensions might not be only source of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This helped
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7338

Answer (score 0):

Check your connected device has enough storage space.
I had this issue when I tried to run in my iPhone. I cleared the storage by deleting couple of apps and tried to install again and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your device's storage.

I had this issue and deleting some apps was the only solution for me...

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem by switching to a different simulator (iPhone6 instead of iPhone6s) in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Switch OFF your Phone and ON.

Now install your app ,its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you run in device then remove previous app . It will work .