# "Installation Failed: Invalid Argument" after moving to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7

After agreeing to the "Upgrade to recommended settings" dialog in Xcode 7, my app build but no longer runs on the simulator. The simulator launches properly, but just sits on the home screen. Meanwhile, Xcode displays the error:

> Installation Failed
>   Invalid Argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 6.1: Installation Failed "Invalid argument" when trying to run Today application extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037589/xcode-6-1-installation-failed-invalid-argument-when-trying-to-run-today-appli)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because "Upgrade to recommended settings" will change the info.plist's `CFBundleIdentifier` to point to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` instead of the old `$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.

Apple says in the Xcode 7 release notes that `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is now "the recommended place to set the Bundle Identifier for a target." So if you're using `BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` anyplace else in your project, you have to change it to `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` to keep things in sync.

Comment: Yes! I checked my Product Bundle Identifier in Build Settings, and it was blank. I entered the correct value and now my project runs. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because somehow my `info.plist` wasn't selected in my target application, so you just have to go `YourProject` -> `General`, and then look for issues or missing files.

I don't remember clearly what it was that fixed the issue, but that is the last thing I remembered from what actually fixed the issue, after following the accepted answer.