# Installation Failed: Invalid Argument - System Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, git, macos

I know there are lots of posts on this error and it seems like it is a catchall for Xcode.  I have tried all the suggestions in these posts:

[Installation Failed "Invalid argument" when trying to run Today application extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037589/installation-failed-invalid-argument-when-trying-to-run-today-application-exte)

[Installation Failed: Invalid Argument -iOS Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031746/installation-failed-invalid-argument-ios-extension)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7338

And none of them have worked (I tried every answer's suggestion).  I have reverted to older commits that I know never saw this error, done clean clone installs, I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode, restarted my computer, deleted all derived data, and everything else I could possibly think of. Please let me know if you think you have an answer.

Note: I still think there may be an issue with the info.plist, but like I said, even reverting back to an older version doesn't work. Is there potentially a place xcode keeps info.plist files on the local hard drive and references these?

Thanks!

Comment: What were you trying to do when you got this error?

Comment: It happened after following the guide to incorporate Amazon S3 into a swift project. I did so using Pods. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Somehow while installing Amazon AWS using pods in my project, the link to the Info.plist in the build settings of the project was deleted.  I am still not sure how this problem occurred across all versions of the application, even older ones where this would not have been included. By filling this entry in the Build Settings to App_name/Info.plist the project finally compiled again.